# How to differentiate between space and tab while performing file operations in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a dumped(.rem) file with 3 entries per line, separated by tabs - "\t" as shown below.

```
Hello    World    Ocaml
I    like    Ocaml
```

To read from this file, the type is passed in a cast(attrbs) along with the file like this:

```
type attrbs = list (string * string * string);
let chi = (open_in file : attrbs) in
let v = input_value chi in close_in chi
```

Now, I get a list in "v", which I use further. In fact, it also works if the entries are separated by space.

This works fine if all the 3 entries in a row do not contain any spaces within themselves. I would like to use another file which has the first entry as a string with spaces, second entry as a string without spaces, and third entry as any string as shown below:

```
This is with spaces    Thisiswithoutspaces    Thisissomestring
Another one with spaces    Anotheronewithoutspaces    AnotherString
```

If I use the code mentioned, since it does not differentiate between space and tab, it takes only the first three words - "This", "is", and "with". I want it to include the spaces and consider "This is with spaces" as an entire string.

I tried searching the web, but couldn't find any solution for it.

**Update:**

The issue was with the way I read them. If I use specific formats like "%s %s %s", they will work only if we add the @ character like "%s@\t%s@\t%s". It is given under the title: "Scanning indications in format strings" in https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html. The issue is solved.

Comment: It is fine that you found out the answer yourself, but instead of editing the question, it is recommanded to post your own answer (you can accept it after one day).

Answer (score 1):

Glad you managed to do this yourself.

However, I wouldn't recommend using Scanf for that. You can do this:

```
match String.split_on_char '\t' (input_line chi) with
| [a;b;c] -> ...
| exception End_of_file -> ...
| l_wrong_size -> ...
```

This way, you are not only sure to not rely on the quirky behavior of Scanf, but you can also easily specify what to do on malformed input.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the way I read them. If I use specific formats like "%s %s %s", they will work only if we add the @ character like "%s@\t%s@\t%s". It is given under the title: "Scanning indications in format strings" in https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html. The issue is solved.